# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity

Tags: java, pom.xml, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I am following an online tutorial, but came across an error which I am not able to resolve. I have a multimodule Quarkus application. One module is called 'Customer' with an according Customer class which is annotated as an @Entity:

```
package org.agoncal.quarkus.jpa;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import java.time.Instant;

@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;

    public String firstName;
...
```

In another module 'vintage-store', the customerRepository is created andl ooks like this:

```
package org.agoncal.quarkus.panache.repository;

import io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.PanacheRepository;
import org.agoncal.quarkus.jpa.Customer;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;

@ApplicationScoped
public class CustomerRepository implements PanacheRepository<Customer> {}
```

Now, when I try to run `mvn clean install` on the vintage store, there is this test which is failing in the CustomerRepositoryTest file:

```
package org.agoncal.quarkus.panache.repository;

import io.quarkus.test.TestTransaction;
import io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest;
import org.agoncal.quarkus.jpa.Customer;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;

@QuarkusTest
public class CustomerRepositoryTest {
    @Inject
    CustomerRepository repository;

    @Test
    @TestTransaction
    public void shouldCreateAndFindCustomer() throws SQLException {
        Customer customer = new Customer("first name", "last name", "email");

        repository.persist(customer);
        assertNotNull(customer.getId());

        Customer foundCustomer = repository.findById(customer.getId());
        assertEquals("first name", foundCustomer.getFirstName());

    }

}
```

With the following error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity [class org.agoncal.quarkus.jpa.Customer]
        at org.agoncal.quarkus.panache.repository.CustomerRepositoryTest.shouldCreateAndFindCustomer(CustomerRepositoryTest.java:24)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: org.agoncal.quarkus.jpa.Customer
        at org.agoncal.quarkus.panache.repository.CustomerRepositoryTest.shouldCreateAndFindCustomer(CustomerRepositoryTest.java:24)
```

I have looked at it already for a few hours, but do not find the problem. I have found some pointers that it might have to do something with the difference between jakarta and javax, but not sure.

Comment: What is the id value here

Comment: The ID is just a Long

Answer (score 0):

Check your persistence configuration, if it encompasses package and class of yours 'Customer'.

Comment: How to check the persistence configuration? I do not find a persistence.cml file...

Comment: If you don't have META-INF/persistence.xml then JDBC is configured in application.properties

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the only thing that is configured in the application.properties is this: quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=create
What should I add to the file? I guess I do not have to add every single Entity to it? If yes, how shold it be added?

Comment: You need jdbc/datasource configuration, like this:
https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm